# Backup file is not created

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, backup

I want to create a backup of my database in C#. When I click on the update button it shows in the save file dialog correctly, but the backup will not create. After the `save` click it shows the error `"error in catch"`. Here is my code:

---

```
string connection = @"data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\personal_accounting.mdf;integrated security=True;";


using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                ServerConnection srvConn = new ServerConnection(con);

                Server srvr = new Server(srvConn);

                if (srvr != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Backup backupdb = new Backup();
                        backupdb.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
                        backupdb.Database = "personal_accounting";
                        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog savefd = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
                        //SaveFileDialog savefd = new SaveFileDialog();
                        savefd.Filter = "Backup File (*.Bak)|*.Bak";
                        savefd.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
                        Nullable<bool> result = savefd.ShowDialog();
                        if (result==true)
                        {
                            //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("ok");
                            BackupDeviceItem bkpDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(savefd.FileName, DeviceType.File);
                            backupdb.Devices.Add(bkpDevice);
                            backupdb.SqlBackup(srvr);

//--------------------------------- This Will Show Message box -----------------

                            msgnotic = new NotifyMessageManager
                            (
                                Screen.Width,
                                Screen.Height,
                                200,
                                150
                            );
                            msgnotic.Start();
                            NotifyMessage msg = null;
                            msg = new NotifyMessage("img/GreenSkin.png", "message", "Backup has been created",
                                                    () =>
                                                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("operation done!", "message", MessageBoxButton.OK));
                            msgnotic.EnqueueMessage(msg);
//`-----------------------------End msgbox-------------------------------`
                        }

                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error in save backup");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: debug your code. At what line exception is thrown and what is actual message?

Answer (score 1):

You just show the Savefile dialoge first and check if the `DialogResult` is ok and then do the Rest:

```
if(savefd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     //do sql connection, backup creation and ... here
}
```

Comment: the condition is true, problem is in create .bak file 
here:
BackupDeviceItem bkpDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(savefd.FileName, DeviceType.File);
                            backupdb.Devices.Add(bkpDevice);
                            backupdb.SqlBackup(srvr);